# How do I add a result from a loop to a $_POST[] array?

Tags: php, arrays

Good day all, i am working on an Exam app, i created a foreach loop that will pull all the questions from the database and place it in an h4 tag

```
foreach($questions as $key => $question) {
        echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";
        //html output for the questions
        echo "<h4 class='questions'> $question</h4>"."<ol>";//display the questions
```

what i want to do here it to pass the result of the loop `$questions`
to a `$_POST[]` array eg `$question = $_POST['question'];`

i tried doing this:

```
foreach($questions as $id => $question) {
        echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";
        //html output for the questions
        $uQuestions = $question;
        $uQuestions = $_POST['uQuestions'];
        echo "<h4 class='questions'> $question</h4>"."<ol>";//display the questions
```

i got an error

```
Notice: Undefined index: uQuestions in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\exam.php on line 86
```

how do i go about it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Paste your `array()` that you get for `$questions`  in the question

Comment: You really shouldn't modify any superglobals.

Comment: .... what? I don't think you know what `$_POST` is or what it is used for.

Comment: what i want it to be able to post all the items from the loop to a file and also to my database. The correct syntax is what i'm looking for

Comment: @NareshKumar.P I don't get you.

Comment: Paste the array that you get . I shall provide you with solutions

Comment: @NareshKumar.P do you mean the result of the array when i run the code? 

it returned the last item in the loop

Comment: //mySql query here
`$questions = array();
foreach($questionsArray as $question) {
    $questions[$question['questionid']] = $question['name'];
 }`

Comment: //mySql query here
`$questions = array();
foreach($questionsArray as $question) {
    $questions[$question['questionid']] = $question['name'];
 }`

Comment: @NareshKumar.P i had done the mysql queries on a separate file (quiz.php) and some of my user defined function too on another separate file (function_list.php and validation_functions.php)

Comment: @Epodax i know what the `$_POST` superglobal is used for, i was just asking a question so i could get solutions

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you get the assignment wrong. This:

```
$_POST['uQuestions'] = $question;
```

will put $question in $_POST but without a unique identifier. When the loop ends $_POST['uQuestions'] will contains the last $question from the loop.

A solution might be:

```
 $_POST['uQuestions' . $id] = $question;
```

than you will put all questions in $POST

Comment: i tried using that, but it only returned the last item in the loop. I tried writing it to a file to see its output.

Comment: Here's the code i used to write it to file

        '$uQuestions = $question;
        $_POST['uQuestions' . $id] = $question;
        $sQuestions = $question;
        $fName = "currentQuestions.txt";
        $sFile = fopen($fName, 'w');
        fwrite($sFile, $sQuestions);
        fclose($sFile);'

Comment: what syntax will i use to grab all the data in the loop and not the last item?

Comment: From your answer, I am not sure what it is exactly that you want to accomplish. You already have a variable called $questions right? What do you want to do with that variable?